# Naturality of strong-epi-mono factorization

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

We have the following diagram:

[image]

We want to prove the existence of such $h$ with $p$ and $q$ strong epimorphisms.

1. Why can't we apply directly the definition of strong epimorphism to the epimorphism $p$, the monomorphism $j$ and the lift $(q\circ f , g\circ i)$ ? Wouldn't that immediately give an $h$ that makes everything commute?

Borceux instead does this:

[image]

2. Do we ever use $q$ is (strong-)epi and $i$ is mono?

Comment: I agree with $(1)$. In the diagram used by Borceux, I don't understand what the point is. That diagram only assumes that $u$ is a strong epimorphism (and that epi-mono factorisations exist)
, but beyond that I don't see how to follow; given the arrow $s$, what next?

Comment: @FShrike I understand the idea is that $(u,j\circ v)$ and $(k\circ p, l)$ are two epi mono factorizations, therefore $s$ is actually an isomorphism. The $h$ from the beginning will then be $v\circ s^{-1} \circ k$.